# How to call a Custom Hook in a React function

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project in my project I have one custom hook, Now I am trying to call that custom hook in one function but it is showing error like this React Hook "useMediaQuery" is called in function "applyStyle" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter

So someone help me how to resolve this issue

This is my code

This is App.js

`````
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';


const App = () => {
    const [style, setStyle] = useState(null)


    function useMediaQuery() {
        const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState([0]);
        
        useLayoutEffect(() => {
          function updateScreenSize() {
            setScreenSize([window.innerWidth]);
          }
          window.addEventListener("resize", updateScreenSize);
          updateScreenSize();
          return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateScreenSize);
        }, []);
        
        return screenSize;
      }

      const applyStyle = () => {
          if(useMediaQuery() === 320) {
              setStyle({
                  marginBottom: '150px'
              })
          }
      }

return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='first'>
                        <button onClick={applyStyle} style={style}  className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
                        <span className='closeWindow'><i className="far fa-window-close"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <div className='second'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App

````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot the 2 most important [rules of hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks)

It says

> Only call Hooks from React function components. Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. (There is just one other valid place to call Hooks — your own custom Hooks. We’ll learn about them in a moment.)

So your case should be:

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';


const App = () => {
    const [style, setStyle] = useState(null)


    function useMediaQuery() {
        const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState([0]);
        
        useLayoutEffect(() => {
          function updateScreenSize() {
            setScreenSize([window.innerWidth]);
          }
          window.addEventListener("resize", updateScreenSize);
          updateScreenSize();
          return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateScreenSize);
        }, []);
        
        return screenSize;
      }
      
      const mediaQuery = useMediaQuery();

      const applyStyle = () => {
          if(mediaQuery === 320) {
              setStyle({
                  marginBottom: '150px'
              })
          }
      }

return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='first'>
                        <button onClick={applyStyle} style={style}  className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
                        <span className='closeWindow'><i className="far fa-window-close"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <div className='second'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Hi @Robert Titra, thanks for your answer I have one more doubt When I am 0px to 320 px at that time only applyStyle function will call. So when I click button in 320px  then Margin bottom will apply for 320 px screen. But after clicking button in 320 px and when I got to 375 px screen here also Margin bottom applied so can you please help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You should open another question so its easier for me to answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks in either the component or a hook, not in functions of a component. So do it like

```js
// also it is better to define your hook outside the component
function useMediaQuery() {
  const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState([0]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    function updateScreenSize() {
      setScreenSize([window.innerWidth]);
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateScreenSize);
    updateScreenSize();
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateScreenSize);
  }, []);

  return screenSize;
}

const App = () => {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState(null);

  // use your custom hook here
  const mediaQuery = useMediaQuery();

  const applyStyle = () => {
    if (mediaQuery === 320) {
      // use hook values
      setStyle({
        marginBottom: "150px",
      });
    }
  };

  return <div>// render something</div>;
};
```